# How to remove small border from fullscreen canvas in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

When using a fullscreen canvas, such as in the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

canvas = Canvas(root, background = "red")  # I use a red background for visibility.
canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)
```

I get a small (2 pixel) border around my entire screen. This happens on any computer I test the code on.

Is there a way I can remove this border, as in have the canvas fill in the entire screen up to the very edge?

[Image of my full screen, with the fullscreen canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/783c9.png)

Thanks

Comment: There are many configuration options for the canvas.  Have you tried them all to see what effect they have?

Comment: @BryanOakley, I had but managed to overlook highlightthickness, silly me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set this option to zero:

```
canvas = Canvas(root, background="red", highlightthickness=0)
```

Check the [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas.html) to find the full list of options. It can help you to resolve many similar problems.